# Ratio of Gamma function equality.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, gamma-function

Let $m,n\in\mathbb N$ with $m<n$ and $0<s<1$, $1\leq p<\infty$. Is the following holds $$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{sp+p+n-2}{2})\Gamma(\frac{n-m+sp}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n+sp}{2})\Gamma(\frac{sp+p+n-m-2}{2})}=1.$$
Where $\Gamma$ is the usual gamma function.

Clearly for $p=2$, its true.

I'm trying to show this for any $p$ with the above range but couldn't do.

Answer (score 1):

For example with $m=1$ , $n=2$ , $s=\frac12$ , $p=4$

$\Gamma(\frac{sp+p+n-2}{2})= 2$

$\Gamma(\frac{n-m+sp}{2}) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$

$\Gamma(\frac{n+sp}{2}) = 1$

$\Gamma(\frac{sp+p+n-m-2}{2}) = \frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{4}$

$$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{sp+p+n-2}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{n-m+sp}{2}) }{ \Gamma(\frac{n+sp}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{sp+p+n-m-2}{2})} = \frac{2\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}}{1\frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{4}} = \frac43$$

The result is different from $1$.

Thus, $\frac{\Gamma(\frac{sp+p+n-2}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{n-m+sp}{2}) }{ \Gamma(\frac{n+sp}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{sp+p+n-m-2}{2})} $ is not always equal to $1$.